# Calculate distance from one location to many

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of 100 locations and 1 starting point. I would like to know how far it is from each of the locations (i mean road distance not straight line distance) to the starting point with out entering each separately. The 100 points are in an excel sheet. Can I achieve this using Google Maps?

Comment: Do You use WEB api? [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=ru) allows what you are asking for

Comment: Need the following details #1 sample point stored in excel. #2 would you use javascript lib. 

Here is the url for Googles Direction API you can also refer it.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/